# Save HTML as PDF without metadata (e.g. date/time, URL)

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, firefox

In Safari or Firefox, saving a web page as PDF (⌘P > PDF > Save as PDF...) includes the page's title, URL, page number, and date/time in the resulting PDF.

Is there a way to generate a PDF without this metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Before you save the PDF select "Show Details" and select Safari (or whatever) from the drop down, then uncheck "Print headers and footers".

Then save as PDF.

[image: print dialog]